# Android - Java NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, exception, null

i'm trying to make a simple application, but i'm stuck at this nasty error, and i can't find out why...

```
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.coindroid/com.example.coindroid.EUActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at com.example.coindroid.EUActivity.onCreate(EUActivity.java:30)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-06 18:05:04.734: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     ... 11 more
```

so, it's seems that my probleme is at line 30, which is this: list.setAdapter(new EUAdapter(this));
What is wrong ? 
My activity is just like this:

```
    package com.example.coindroid;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.res.Resources; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.BaseAdapter; 
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.widget.ListView; 
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class EUActivity extends Activity {      

ListView list;

        @Override   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
setContentView(R.layout.activity_eu);       
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_eu);

                    list.setAdapter(new EUAdapter(this));        
}

        }

             class SingleRow {  String title;   String description;     int image;  SingleRow(String title, String description, int image)  {       this.title = title;         this.description = description;         this.image = image;     } } class EUAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        ArrayList<SingleRow> list;  Context context;    EUAdapter(Context c)    {       context = c;        list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();      Resources res = c.getResources();       String[] titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);       String[] descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.description);        int[] images = {R.drawable.queenvictoria1841jpg};
                    for(int i=0;i<1;i++)        {           list.add(new SingleRow(titles[i], descriptions[i], images[i]));         }
                }
                @Override   public int getCount() {
                    return list.size();     }

        @Override   public Object getItem(int i) {
                    return list.get(i);     }

        @Override   public long getItemId(int i) {
                    return i;   }

        @Override   public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);       View row
    = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, viewGroup, false);
                    TextView title = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);         TextView description = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.year);       ImageView image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    SingleRow temp = list.get(i);
                    title.setText(temp.title);      description.setText(temp.description);      image.setImageResource(temp.image);
                    return row;     }   
             }
```

thanks guys in advance !

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. To post code example use `{}` button from editor menu, not `"` which creates quote. They both create gray background, but only `{}` will keep line separators, and will add proper formatting. Remember that well written and formatted questions have higher chance to be answered (some people tend to skip questions if they see that author didn't put enough effort to create them).

Comment: I guess you will have to fix the formatting if you want someone's help

Comment: what is line no: 30 in EUActivity.java???

Comment: Seriously what did you do while posting the question. I tried to edit it and it was totally messed up. Thank god @Lal edited it before me.  :D

Comment: I too was totally confused while editing and left it half way.. @Rohit5k2

Comment: Did you try to read anything about android? Why are you referring to a layout in this `list = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_eu);`?

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> list = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_eu);
> ```

Your `list` is null. You cannot find anything with a `R.layout` id. Use an `R.id` id that corresponds to your listview in the `activity_eu` layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return view instead of row in the getview method of your adapter

View view = inflater.---

Answer (score 0):

As @laalto mentioned

replace

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_eu);
```

with

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_eu);
```

as you are finding views by id with `findViewByID()` from R.java